# Conexión por Ajax a Servicio Web SOAP

Tags: javascript, java, web, webservice, soap

Tengo desarrollado un webservice en java tipo SOAP en Eclipse que inserta películas en una base de datos. El webservice está testeado con SOAPUI y funciona correctamente. El servicio es publicado mediante Endpoint en la siguiente url: http://localhost/academia/peliculas?wsdl

Ahora lo que necesito es crearme una web y conectar a dicho servicio mediante *JavaScript*.

El código *JavaScript* que he desarrollado es el siguiente:

```
window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("enviar").onclick = function(){

        var id = document.getElementById("id");
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
        
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/academia/peliculas?wsdl",true);
        
        var sr = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dao="http://dao.hlc.com/">' +
                '<soapenv:Header/>' +
                '<soapenv:Body>' +
                '<dao:insertar>' +
                '<arg0>' + id.value + '</arg0>' +
                '<arg1>' + nombre.value + '</arg1>' +
                '</dao:insertar>' +
                '</soapenv:Body>' +
                '</soapenv:Envelope>';
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    alert("Inserción realizada. Comprobar consola para ver la respuesta")
                }
                else if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    alert("Servicio no encontrado");
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/xml');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*');
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
        id.value = "";
        nombre.value = "";

    }
    
}
```

Cuando pruebo la web y depuro el código, veo que en la línea: `xmlhttp.send(sr)` se produce el siguiente error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Por favor, ¿Alguien sabe lo que está ocurriendo?

Sospecho de temas relacionados con CORS pero no se como solucionarlo.

Gracias por adelantado

Un saludo

Comment: No hace POST al ?wsdl Ese URL es para devolver información del servicio web y no para pasar datos.

Comment: He buscado información y las peticiones a servicios SOAP se hacen a partir de la dirección del wsdl. ¿Podrías indicarme como hacer la petición de forma correcta? Gracias

Comment: Usualmente es el mismo URL sin ?wsdl .  WSDL significa (en inglés Web Services Descriptor Language.  Es para obtener información de cualquier servicio, especilamente los metodos que se puede llamar.

Comment: No es correcto, si pongo la dirección sin el ?wsdl el error es el mismo: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Acá la solución es que pruebes una petición SOAP usando un cliente (como SOAPui), al hacer esa petición de prueba, podrás ver qué esperar en la respuesta. Y efectivamente, `?wsdl` te va a entregar el contrato. Al no saber cómo está el servicio SOAP, es difícil darte más ideas